# Upgrade From SWF 1.0 to 2 - Null ModelandView in handle method in HandlerAdapter

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

In `DispacherServlet`, the `HandlerAdapter` will handle the request and return an appropriate `ModelandView` :

```
mv = ha.handle(processedRequest, response, mappedHandler.getHandler());
```

My question is what will happen if the `ModelandView` is null? Will any JSP be rendered?

If no JSP is being rendered, then shouldn't the page just be a blank or an error as Spring does not know what to render? Surprisingly, I am finding that this is not the case and a page is being rendered.

Comment: Why are you mentioning WebFlow? It is confusing. If you are talking only about Spring MVC handlers, please remove the WebFlow reference.

Comment: Pavel, I have removed webflow from my question.We are using a spring webflow with spring mvc in front architecture. It is irrelevant to the question. I would just like to know what how spring mvc proceeds if a null ModelandView is returned

Comment: I've tried to answer the question without success... if a page is being rendered, there must be something strange in your handler configuration. What kind of page is being rendered? Can you specify your configuration and handler method signature (including annotations)?

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the source and there is a special interface `RequestToViewNameTranslator` for situations when handlers don't return views or view names. The default implementation is [`DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.html).

The reasoning behind this is probably to allow "convention over configuration" when rendering views based on requests.

---

**UPDATE:** The above statements are true only if you return empty `ModelAndView`. For `null` the request processing should not continue => hence blank page. If you are not experiencing such behavior, there is something strange going on.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about the interface. Null ModelandView is not an error condition, Spring MVC just assumes that somebody else has taken care of rendering the view and everything goes ahead as normal. This kind of situation will arise when you combine Spring MVC with Spring Webflow as is discussed in the link. http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?66246-ModelAndView-getting-null-in-post-handle-interceptor-while-upgrading-webflows

Comment: Yes, I was not suggesting that `null` MaV is an error (I used this fact many times). If your question is really about MVC and SWF integration, than you should know that SWF uses its own view rendering mechanisms. SWF renders its views in request handling phase. So the view is rendered long before it gets to the MVC's view rendering phase.

Comment: You should probably rephrase the question to ask what are you trying to achieve and whether there is a specific problem you are trying to solve.